# Adding OpenStreetMap layers to QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, layers, style

I have OpenStreetMap (OSM) data that I've loaded into a Spatialite database.

How do I get it to look like OSM?

I shouldn't have to add and style each layer individually but I can't figure out what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This github page has some QGIS style files for OSM data: https://github.com/3liz/osm-in-qgis

Other sources can be found at

http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/osm/

http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/style/

You might test them with some smaller test data to see if the database queries work with your spatialite database.

Comment: I followed the directions on that github link and just switched to shape files and that seems to be working for me. Thanks a bunch!